# ClassNotFound on new Symfony bundle

Tags: symfony

I want to add a bundle to create a blog on my Symfony 3.2.1 app.
I tried to create a bundle without generating it, so I have done it reproducing the same structure than the default "AppBundle" :
I have create under "src" a "BlogBundle" folder, and under it, a "BlogBundle.php" file containing the same code than the AppBundle.php file (changing names...). I have then declared it in the AppKernel.php file.

But I had a "ClassNotFound" on my app.
So I removed everything and use the console `generate:bundle` script.
But even with the script, I have the same problem...

The bundle is declared in AppKernel with the code `new BlogBundle\BlogBundle()`

Error (no error in the dev.log file of the app) :

```
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 41: Attempted to load class
"BlogBundle" from namespace "BlogBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

in AppKernel.php line 41
at AppKernel->registerBundles() in Kernel.php line 403
at Kernel->initializeBundles() in Kernel.php line 113
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 165
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 43
at require('/media/jon/Projets/Projets/heroDelHumanite/Sylius/boutique/web/app_dev.php') in router_dev.php line 40
```

`

Someone has an idea of the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you namespace the classes approprietly? Maybe you need to `composer dump autoload`.

Comment: The namespace has been generated by the `generate:bundle` script. In the src/BlogBundle/BlogBundle.php, the namespace is `namespace BlogBundle;`

Comment: Update your question with the actual error message.  I suppose it's possible that it is looking for a different class entirely?  And this is a brand new S3 app?  Not upgrading and you don't have a gazillion other dependencies?

Comment: I haven't found log message in log file. The only message I found is the one displayed on the page. It is a 3.2.1 Symfony app. @Cerad, I didn't understood your last sentence.

Comment: It certainly looks like BlogBundle is the problem.  Double check the spelling of src/BlogBundle/BlogBundle.php.  It is case sensitive though if you used generate:bundle then I don't see how there could be a mistake.  Maybe check the directory permissions and delete the cache directory though again I don't see how they could be a factor.

Comment: I have double checked the name, everything. So I have deleted everything related to BlogBundle (maybe there was a problem from the beginning, when I tried to do it without generation), and my app worked. Again, I tried to generate a bundle named TotoBundle with the command `php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=TotoBundle` and let everything to default. I tried to access my app, I have the same error... Maybe something is missing for the generator ? I had to add the `new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle()` because it wasn't by default in my app(my app come from Sylius)

Comment: Sylius is a shop Symfony app that I try to extend to fit my needs.

Comment: ... And no pb with file permissions, which are the same than the default AppBundle.

Comment: A mystery.  The "my app come from Sylius" raises a red flag.  That is kind of what I meant before which I asked if you had a bunch of other stuff going on.  Who knows what you really have in composer.json.  Commit your complete code to a github repository and I'll take a look.  Otherwise, start with a new S3 project, convince yourself that generate:bundle works as designed then add the sylius stuff in a bit at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem : in the autoload param of composer.json, I had src/AppBundle et pas "src/" only, so, I think, only AppBundle was autoloaded :

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle/"
        },
```

Thanks all for your help !